# List<> to MemoryStream Conversion

Tags: c#, stream

Hi I am new to C# and I want to convert List<> type to MemoryStream:

```
List<String> listType=new List<String>;
MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();
```

and If I am doing like this-

```
MemoryStream listToStream=(MemoryStream)listType;
```

it is showing as suspicious cast.
please help!!

Comment: You cannot *convert* a list into a memory stream. It's two completely different types. Do you maybe want to serialize it? If so, do you care how exactly it's serialized (JSON, XML, Binary)?

Comment: So a list is... well a list of something, in this case strings, a `MemoryStream` is an array of `byte`. How do you want to *magic* them in. You will need to invent some rules, and only when knowing those rules can we help you

Comment: @nvoigt yes exactly I want to serialize it..is there any way for the same?

Answer (score 2):

If serialization is what you want, then is it to xml or json?

They are pretty much the same in terms of performance: [Json and Xml serialization, what is better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916591/json-and-xml-serialization-what-is-better-performance)

A excellent example is the following:http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/07/xml-serialization-of-collections/

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XMLSerialization
{  
    [XmlRoot("CompanyEmployees")]
    public class EmployeeList
    {
        [XmlArray("EmployeeListing")]

        [XmlArrayItem("Employee", typeof(Employee))]
        public List employeeList;

        // Constructor
        public EmployeeList()
        {
            employeeList = new List();
        }

        public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            employeeList.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

And actual serialization

```
private void SerializeList()
{
    // Create an instance of the EmployeeList class
    EmployeeList employeeList = new EmployeeList();

    // Create a few instances of the Employee class
    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.Name = "John";
    emp1.Surname = "Smith";
    emp1.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 10, 08);
    emp1.Sex = Employee.EmployeeSex.Male;
    emp1.Position = "Software Engineer";

    Employee emp2 = new Employee();
    emp2.Name = "David";
    emp2.Surname = "McGregor";
    emp2.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1973, 01, 13);
    emp2.Sex = Employee.EmployeeSex.Male;
    emp2.Position = "Product Manager";

    Employee emp3 = new Employee();
    emp3.Name = "Sarah";
    emp3.Surname = "Crow";
    emp3.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1983, 11, 23);
    emp3.Sex = Employee.EmployeeSex.Female;
    emp3.Position = "Software Tester";

    // Add the employees to the list   
    employeeList.AddEmployee(emp1);
    employeeList.AddEmployee(emp2);
    employeeList.AddEmployee(emp3);

    // Create an instance of System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(employeeList.GetType());

    // Create an instance of System.IO.TextWriter 
    // to save the serialized object to disk
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\Employee\\employeeList.xml");

    // Serialize the employeeList object
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, employeeList);

    // Close the TextWriter
    textWriter.Close();
}
```